# Forgotten administrator password in windows 2003 server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, administrator

I tried to reset administrator password from following steps is below but unable to change administrator password.

1. Set the server computer to boot from USB Bootable drive, and boot the server from Windows server bootable image.

2.When install options appear, I select repair windows by command.

3.When command prompt appears, I type in command prompt "net user administrator password123" to reset the new password to the administrator user.

4.And reboot the computer after reboot I tried to login with new password but unable to login.

So please help me.

Comment: Please don't cross post questions between SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use offline nt password and registry editor. Here http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ is the original source.